# Let $\psi(x)=e^{-a|x|^2}$, with $ x \epsilon \textbf{R}$. Evaluate $\frac{(\| |x|^m \psi \|_2)(\| |y|^m \hat{\psi} \|_2)}{{\| \psi \|}_2^2}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

1. Let $\psi(x)=e^{-a|x|^2}$, with $ x \epsilon \textbf{R}$. Evaluate $\frac{(\| |x|^m \psi \|_2)(\| |y|^m \hat{\psi} \|_2)}{{\| \psi \|}_2^2}$
2. Show that the inequality $(\| |x| \psi \|_2)(\| |y| \hat{\psi} \|_2) \geq \frac{(2 \pi)^\frac{1}{2}}{2} \| \psi \|_2^2$ is exact for these $\psi$'s.
3. Can the inequality $(\| |x|^m \psi \|_2)(\| |y|^m \hat{\psi} \|_2) \geq C \| \psi \|_2^2$ be valid for every $\psi \epsilon L^2(\textbf{R})$, with C independent of $\psi$?

Note $\psi(x)$ is equal to the Gaussian, which we know the fourier transformation of the Gaussian is $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^\frac{-\pi^2y^2}{a}$.

**Evaluate $\frac{(\| |x|^m \psi \|_2)(\| |y|^m \hat{\psi} \|_2)}{{\| \psi \|}_2^2}$**

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\| |x|^m \psi \|_2 & =(\int_\textbf{R} (|x|^me^{-a|x|^2})^2 \,d|x|)^\frac{1}{2} \\
& =(\int_\textbf{R} |x|^{2m}e^{-a|x|^4} \,d|x|)^\frac{1}{2}=\ldots \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

**How do I continue?**

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\| |y|^m \hat{\psi} \|_2 & =(\int_\textbf{R} (|y|^m \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^\frac{-\pi^2y^2}{a})^2 \,d|x|)^\frac{1}{2} \\
& =(\int_\textbf{R} |y|^2m \frac{\pi}{a}e^\frac{-2\pi^2y^2}{a} \,d|x|)^\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

**How do I continue?**

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\| \psi \|_2^2 & =\int_\textbf{R} (e^{-a|x|^2})^2 \,dx \\
& =\int_\textbf{R} e^{-2a|x|^2} \,dx \\
& =\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2a}} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

So, $\frac{(\| |x|^m \psi \|_2)(\| |y|^m \hat{\psi} \|_2)}{{\| \psi \|}_2^2}=\frac{}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2a}}}$

**Show that the inequality $(\| |x| \psi \|_2)(\| |y| \hat{\psi} \|_2) \geq \frac{(2 \pi)^\frac{1}{2}}{2} \| \psi \|_2^2$ is exact for these $\psi$'s.**

I believe that this result will come out as soon as we prove number one.

**Can the inequality $(\| |x|^m \psi \|_2)(\| |y|^m \hat{\psi} \|_2) \geq C \| \psi \|_2^2$ with C independent of $\psi$?**
I am not sure if it is sure or not.

Comment: $(e^{-ax^2})^2\neq e^{-ax^4}$

Comment: @Semiclassical Ok How do I do the evaluation then?

Comment: They're gaussian integrals, so you should be able to evaluate them. (Either by deriving them yourself, or looking them up.)